# window shadow on firefox

Tags: firefox, java

i have Dell G7 with geforce 2060 and latest drivers with latest Elementary
i have black shadow on letf and top when web aplication opens new firefox window.
on java mouse is not sinhronized with java-fx window
cursor marks clickable top left edge of window.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Many people do, myself included

Comment: Yup I have the same issue. Is this not a firefox issue? Does not seem to happen in any other app at all?

Answer (score 1):

This is still happening as of November 14 with Firefox 82.0.3. There's a [mozilla thread](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1666839) about it that indicates that it's an elementary-OS-specific issue and that it's a regression. They've been kicking the can down the road by marking the problem as "wontfix" for each successive Firefox version rather than addressing it. If this is specifically an elementary OS problem, can the underlying cause be fixed in the OS?

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround: in the file `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop` change the line `Exec=firefox %u` to `Exec=env GTK_CSD=0 firefox %u`. Found this solution at https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/j3h3fp/firefox_users_anyone_seeing_an_issue_where/